# VueJs - dynamic class in a loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Every time I select a `div` element, I want only that element to change color. With my current code, when I click an element, it changes the color for all items using the variable `color`, but I don't know how to make only the selected element change color.

This is my code:

```html
 <div class="row">        
   <div v-for="(item, index) in seatShows" :key="index">
     <div class="col-auto" @click="select(item)">
       <div class="icon icon-shape text-white" :class="[color]">
         <img src="/images/butaca2-lg.png" class="position-relative">
         <a class="text-white position-absolute"> {{item.id_seat}} </a>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>    
 </div>
```

And this is my Vue Code:

```js
export default {
  props: ['route'],
  data() {
    return {
      seatShows: this.route,
      color: 'bg-seat-empty',
    }
  },
  methods:{
    select(item) {
      this.color = 'bg-primary';
      console.log(item) ;
      return this.color;
    },
    sel(item) {
      console.log(item.status_ticket);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you assign `color` class to all elements in a loop. So when you update it, all elements will have that color.

If you want each element to have a different color, then you can just add `color` property to each element and change it using a method:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in seatShows" :key="index">
  <div class="col-auto" @click="select(item)" >
   <div class="icon icon-shape text-white" :class="[item.color]">
     ...
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
seatShows: [
  {id: 0, title: 'item1', color: 'bg-seat-empty'},
  {id: 1, title: 'item2', color: 'bg-seat-empty'},
  {id: 2, title: 'item3', color: 'bg-seat-empty'}
]

...

methods: {
  getSeatShows() {
    // Get seatShows data
    // ...

    // Add property "color" to seatShows data 
    this.seatShows.forEach(element => { 
      if (element.status === 0) {
        element['color'] = 'bg-seat-empty'
      }
      else if (element.status === 1) {
        element['color'] = 'bg-seat-full'
      }      
    })
  },
  select(item) {
    // Method 1
    this.seatShows[item.id].color = item.color

    // Method 2 (can be used to find items by some other unique property)
    // let itemIndex = this.seatShows.findIndex(element => element.id === item.id)
    // this.seatShows[itemIndex].color = item.color
  }
}
```

Comment: there would be no other way since "seatShows = this.route" is a dynamic json that comes from the Laravel blade and has no "color" field

Comment: @ErickRabpit well, you can add that property after you get the json and save it into `seatShows`, right? Just run the following command and it will add this property with default value `bg-seat-empty` to each element of the list: `this.seatShows.forEach(element => element['color'] = 'bg-seat-empty')`

Comment: I forget an important detail, in the object "seatShows" there is a "status" field in which if in the BD it is:
"status = 0" then "color = bg-seat-empty" and if "status = 1" then "color = bg-seat-full", but this should be loaded at the time of filling in the data, so I guess I should put it in the created method of Vue but I don't know how to do it

Comment: I added a method that modifies the data. Adapt it to your code. You just have to run it after you get the data

Comment: I recover "seatShows" from the Laravel blade. but I will try to do it as you indicate

Comment: I have a problem, when I have the data filled with a static array of objects as in your example the select () method works `select(item){
     return this.seatShows[item.id_ticket].color = 'bg-primary';
    },` but when I put the "route" variable that I extract from laravel it doesn't work when I click, route is also in JSON format

Answer (score 0):

Well since you are using Vue. I would suggest a more component oriented solution. Convert your inner `div` into a component:

```html
<template>
  <div class="col-auto" @click="select(item)">
    <div class="icon icon-shape text-white" :class="[current]">
      <img src="/images/butaca2-lg.png" class="position-relative">
      <a class="text-white position-absolute">{{item.id_seat}}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    defaultClass: { type: String, default: "bg-secondary" },
    isSelected: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    selectedClass: { type: String, default: "" },
    item: Object
  },
  computed: {
    current: function() {
      return this.isSelected ? this.selectedClass : this.defaultClass;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    select(item) {
      this.$emit("selected", item); // emit the selected item
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

And then use it like this:

```html
<template>
  <div class="row">
    <div v-for="(item, index) in seatShows" :key="index">
      <Select
        selectedClass="bg-primary"
        v-on:selected="select(item)"
        :item="item"
        :isSelected="selectedItem === item"
      ></Select>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Select from "./Select";
export default {
  components: {
    Select
  },
  props: ["route"],
  data() {
    return {
      seatShows: [
        { title: "item1", id_seat: "1" },
        { title: "item2", id_seat: "2" },
        { title: "item3", id_seat: "3" }
      ],
      selectedItem: null // provide a selected item
    };
  },
  methods: {
    select(item) {
      this.selectedItem = item; // when selected populate it
      console.log(item);

    }       
  }
};
</script>
```

Here is the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-cannon-gxyw1)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is `item` so I would suggest to use your index to switch between classes:

```
<div class="row">        
   <div v-for="(item, index) in seatShows" :key="index">
     <div class="col-auto" @click="select(index)">
       <div class="icon icon-shape text-white" :class="index === currentIndex ? primary : empty">
         <img src="/images/butaca2-lg.png" class="position-relative">
         <a class="text-white position-absolute"> {{item.id_seat}} </a>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>    
 </div>
```

And you component data:

```
export default {
  props: ['route'],
  data() {
    return {
      seatShows: this.route,
      empty: 'bg-seat-empty',
      primary: 'bg-primary',
      currentIndex: -1
    }
  },
  methods:{
    select(index) {
      this.currentIndex = index;
    }
  }
}
```